# Expected 2D array error not getting resolved

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

i am trying to use my machine learning model on dataset where i have only two columns while standard scaling them,i got the error expected 2D array but got 1 .

Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
"""from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)"""

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Fitting SVR to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

# Visualising the SVR results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Truth or Bluff (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Position level')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.show()
```

when i try to put

```
y = sc_y.fit_transform([y])
```

like this i received no error but when i execute next 3 lines i receive another error.

which is `bad input shape (1, 10)`

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are both the two columns, input?

Comment: No , X is the input value and y is the actual output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StandardScaler() function in sklearn expects the input(X) to be in the following format:

X : numpy array of shape [n_samples, n_features]

So, reshape X to (-1,1) if you have only one feature column.

```
sc_X.fit_transform(X.reshape[-1,1])
```

This should work!

Comment: i just changed 

sc_X.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1)) and it worked fine. Thank you so much for your help. You are amazing.

Comment: Happy to help :) Thanks